# Out of date prometheus alerts keeps firing

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We have an alert in our AlertManager config

```yaml
      - alert: NoMessageForTooLong
        expr: >
          changes(kafka_topic_partition_current_offset{
            topic!="__consumer_offsets",
            topic!~"^(strimzi\\.cruisecontrol\\.partitionmetricsamples|strimzi\\.cruisecontrol\\.modeltrainingsamples|__strimzi-topic-operator-kstreams-topic-store-changelog|__strimzi_store_topic).*"}[10m]) == 0
        for: 10s
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: "No message for 10 minutes"
          description: "There are no messages in topic {{ $labels.topic}}/partition {{ $labels.partition }} for 10 minutes"
```

This was firing for a specific kafka topic `topic-1`

While the alert was active, we removed the topic `topic-1`.

The alert does not show as active in AlertManager, but every 24 hours it keeps being sent to our Slack channel.

I assume the issue is that it cannot be resolved, as Prometheus never finds a new value for that metric with the same labels since the topic no longer exist.

A bit strange that is is once per 24 hours since we have set `repeatInterval: 12h`

Is it something in the alert rule that should be changed to prevent this from happening? Or do we need to manually clear things like this out?

Answer (score 0):

Behaviour that you are reporting is rather strange: if you removed offending topic, I'd expect metric with offset for it to disappear, and rule to be automatically resolved.

Check if metric `kafka_topic_partition_current_offset{topic="topic-1"}` is still present. If it is, that's on the exporter's side (maybe it keeps reporting offsets for deleted topics for a reason, check documentation). *

If metrics are kept by exporter and you cannot (or don't want to) make it stop, you might manually override rule.
For example, expression like

```
changes(kafka_topic_partition_current_offset{
            topic!="__consumer_offsets",
            topic!~"^(strimzi\\.cruisecontrol\\.partitionmetricsamples|strimzi\\.cruisecontrol\\.modeltrainingsamples|__strimzi-topic-operator-kstreams-topic-store-changelog|__strimzi_store_topic).*"}[10m]) == 0
unless 
changes(kafka_topic_partition_current_offset[2d]) == 0
```

will keep alert alive, unless there were no changes in last two days, and then alert will be resolved automatically.

---

Your expectation of behaviour of `repeatInterval` is correct. Please check if your configuration is in fact applied (can be seen on the `/#/status` page of alertmanager)

---

* : all of this based on the assumption that you don't use pushgateway or similar solutions. If you in fact use them - you might have an issue there: pushgateway keeps reporting last value of the metric even if it's long gone.

Answer (score -1):

Johnathan, the issue at hand is that the alert cannot be resolved because Prometheus never finds a new value for that metric with the same labels, as the topic no longer exists. As for the alert being sent to your Slack channel every 24 hours, despite the specified 12-hour repeat interval, this behavior occurs because AlertManager relentlessly retries sending an alert until it is successfully delivered. In this case, the alert is not successfully delivered due to the non-existent topic, leading to repeated attempts every 24 hours.

My first suggestion here is to modify the alert rule to include an annotation that instructs AlertManager to delete the alert after a certain time period. You can do this by adding the following annotation to the alert rule:

**yaml**

```
annotations:
  delete.after: 24h
```

This annotation informs AlertManager to automatically delete the alert after 24 hours, regardless of its delivery status. It ensures the alert is not retried indefinitely. Alternatively, you can manually clear the alert from AlertManager. To do this, utilize the following curl command, replacing  with the name of the alert you wish to clear:

**bash**

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:9090/alerts/<alert-name>
```

In case you opt for modifying the alert rule, it's advisable to set the "delete.after" period to be greater than the repeat interval, ensuring the alert is deleted before it has a chance to be retried. Check thisexample of a modified alert rule with the "delete.after" annotation set to 24 hours.

**yaml**

```
alert: NoMessageForTooLong
expr: >
  changes(kafka_topic_partition_current_offset{
    topic!="__consumer_offsets",
    topic!~"^(strimzi\.cruisecontrol\.partitionmetricsamples|strimzi\.cruisecontrol\.modeltrainingsamples|__strimzi-topic-operator-kstreams-topic-store-changelog|__strimzi_store_topic).*"}[10m]) == 0
for: 10s
labels:
  severity: warning
annotations:
  summary: "No message for 10 minutes"
  description: "There are no messages in topic {{ $labels.topic}}/partition {{ $labels.partition }} for 10 minutes"
  delete.after: 24h
```

Comment: Can you show any documentation regarding `delete.after` annotation? Or is this a case of classical LLM hallucination and not checking your answer before posting it?

Comment: I wonder the same. Also the `delete.after` example uses a dot, while all other examples from the official documentation uses `_`.